# Struggling to get Function to return table of results

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to Postgres development and am struggling to get a function working , to return a table of data.

However I am not getting the correct table of results

Here is my table definition:

```
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.device;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbo.device
(
    deviceid uuid NOT NULL,
    serialnumber character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    productcode character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    description character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    softwareversion character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    build character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    builddate timestamp with time zone,
    assigned boolean,
    groupid uuid,
    updateddatetime timestamp with time zone,
    restartpointerno integer,
    deviceconnectionindex integer,
    organisationid uuid,
    CONSTRAINT pk__device__49e123311461d246 PRIMARY KEY (deviceid),
    CONSTRAINT fk_device_organisation_organisationid FOREIGN KEY (organisationid)
        REFERENCES dbo.organisation (organisationid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fkdevice951246 FOREIGN KEY (groupid)
        REFERENCES dbo.groups (groupid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fkdevice_deviceconnectiontype FOREIGN KEY (deviceconnectionindex)
        REFERENCES dbo.deviceconnectiontype (deviceconnectionindex) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.device
    OWNER to postgres;
```

And this is my function defintion:

```
DROP FUNCTION spgetdevicedetails();


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spgetdevicedetails()
  RETURNS TABLE (ProductCode        text,   -- also visible as OUT param in function body
                 SerialNumber       text,
                 Description        text,
                 SoftwareVersion    text,
                 Build              text,
                 BuildDate          text,
                 Assigned           text
               )
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
#variable_conflict use_column
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
        SELECT
            ProductCode ::text,
            SerialNumber ::text ,
            Description ::text,
            SoftwareVersion ::text,
            Build ::text,
            BuildDate ::text,
            Assigned ::text
        FROM 
            dbo.Device;
        
END
$func$;
```

```
Im getting results like this in 1 column:
"(ACSR-3600-A,939029,""Metrology Test Receiver"",1.2.928,4829,,)"
"(TGRF-4024-A,940860,""Office Desk"",1.2.928,4843,,)"
"(TR-3020-A,876302,TR-3020-A,1.4.1,4829,,)"
"(TGRF-4602-A,926371,""Office Bookcase"",1.2.928,4843,,)"
```

How I can get it to display data as follows:

Product Code      SerialNumber     Description                  SoftwareVersion
ACSR-3600-A       939029           Metrology Test Receiver      1.2.928
TGRF-4024-A       940860           Metrology Test Receiver      1.2.928
ACSR-3600-A       876302           Metrology Test Receiver      1.4.1

Comment: In which application do you run the function and get the results "in 1 column"? psql, pgAdmin, something else?

Comment: select * from myfunction()

Comment: I am running this in PGAdmin4

Comment: Ok guys 
I have got this working.. 
i should be calling it as follows:

select * from spgetdevicedetails();

I have since added a parameter to filter

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spgetdevicedetails(s2 text)

and now can call the function successfully :

select * from spgetdevicedetails('940860');

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you even use a function for this? A view would do the same job. And if you want to use a function, at least use the SQL language instead of plpgsql. It's faster and can be optimized during planning, for example when using WHERE conditions on the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you call a table function with

```
SELECT spgetdevicedetails();
```

you will get each result row as a single column of a composite type, much like if you use an explicit whole-row reference:

```
SELECT spgetdevicedetails
FROM spgetdevicedetails();
```

You should use a table function in the same place in an SQL function where you use a table, namely in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM spgetdevicedetails();
```